# How to find the area under a portion of a histogram?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

```
muhats = replicate(200000,mean(rexp(18, rate = 3))*exp(((-1/2)*mean(rexp(18, rate = 3)))) )
myhist <- hist(muhats)
plot(myhist)
```

I have the above density function, is there an R command that will give me the area between 2 points under the histogram? 
I cant seem to find anywhere?

I trying to find a point c on the x axis, such that the area to the left of c is 0.09

Comment: Did you mean `myhist <- hist(g, probability=T)` ?

Comment: Do you definitely want the area under the histogram? Or are you trying to estimate a quantile from your data?  There are better ways to estimate quantiles than looking at area under a histogram.

Comment: @Dason trying to estimate a quantile

Comment: are `g` and `muhats` the same thing?

Comment: @G5W yes thats correct

Comment: @r2evans thats is correct!

Comment: `quantile(g, 0.09)`

Comment: yso, you agreed that it was a mistake in your code, I've edited it accordingly. Please realize that (1) questions should be self-contained and accurate (without known unrelated mistakes/typos), and (2) comments are often skipped by readers or hidden by the interface (when there are many). Do not rely on comments to contain the only corrections to irrelevant mistakes.

Comment: @r2evans and now it has been edited in such a way as to make my answer nonsensical since we went with `muhat` instead of `g`. I'll edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: Sorry Allan, best-intentions gone awry :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function, which numerically integrates the density using the trapezoidal rule, and returns the first value that exceeds a particular value:

```
density_area_exceeds <- function(vector, limit)
{
  d <- density(vector)
  d$x[cumsum(diff(d$x) * (d$y[-1] + d$y[-length(d$y)])/2) > limit][1]
}
```

So you can do:

```
density_area_exceeds(muhat, 0.09)
#> [1] 0.1961847
```

So the area of the density to the left of this point on the x axis is 0.09.

Note though, this gives roughly the same answer as just doing:

```
quantile(g, 0.09)
#>        9% 
#> 0.1971049
```

Comment: Would `ecdf` be more appropriate?

Comment: @r2evans it's more like the inverse of `ecdf` I think. If you do `ecdf(g)(quantile(g, x))` you get `x`